# How to evaluate the following trigonometric sum?

Tags: summation, recreational-mathematics, trigonometric-series

I recently learned summing a trigonometric series where the $i^{th}$ term is $\cos(i\theta)$ where the angles are in arithmetic progression. The idea is to multiply the sum $S$ by $\sin\theta$ and reduce it to a telescopic series.

The same process can be applied if the $i^{th}$ term is $\cos^2(i\theta)$ by using the half-angle identity.

But suppose, the $i^{th}$ term is $\frac{1}{1 + m\cdot \tan^2(i\theta)}$. We get the previous series (whose sum is known) if $m = 1$

How can we compute the sum if $m \neq 1$
$$
S = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{1 + m\cdot \tan^2(i\theta)}
$$

I tried differentiating $S$ and tried multiplying it with trigonometric functions but to no avail. I went through various questions posted in this site in the Trigonometric series and Summation tags but still made no progress.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that the sum has a nice closed form expression?

Comment: @SahajSatishSharma, no I don't. I was wondering if this would open up any techniques or areas of math that I am unaware of

Answer (score 2):

$$S_m = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{1 + m\, \tan^2(i\theta)}\qquad \text{with} \qquad  m>1$$
Using Euler representation of the tangent function
$$S_m=-\frac n{m-1}+\frac{\sqrt{m}}{(m-1) \log \left(e^{2 i \theta }\right)}\, \color{red}{\large \text{A}} $$

where
$$ \color{red}{\large \text{A}}=\psi _{e^{2 i \theta }}^{(0)}\left(n-\frac{\log
   \left(1-\frac{2}{\sqrt{m}+1}\right)}{\log \left(e^{2 i \theta
   }\right)}\right)-\psi _{e^{2 i \theta
   }}^{(0)}\left(n-\frac{\log
   \left(1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{m}-1}\right)}{\log \left(e^{2 i \theta
   }\right)}\right)+$$
$$\psi _{e^{2 i \theta }}^{(0)}\left(-\frac{\log
   \left(1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{m}-1}\right)}{\log \left(e^{2 i \theta
   }\right)}\right)-\psi _{e^{2 i \theta
   }}^{(0)}\left(-\frac{\log
   \left(1-\frac{2}{\sqrt{m}+1}\right)}{\log \left(e^{2 i \theta
   }\right)}\right)$$ where appear the q-digamma function.

Comment: +1 for solving and for introducing me to the new concept of q-digamma function. But I couldn't figure out how you got to the final answer.